# python .get function adds a newline, how do i remove it?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I am using the tkinter add on within python and I am ".get"ing input text from a text widget,

When i do so it decides to add a newline.

I don't want this newline because it messes with my CSV savefile and means i cants read my CSV file properly from python.

how do i get rid of the "\n"?

I have tried ".rstrip" and ".splitlines" neither work.

[This is what is displayed by the code...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYYCu.jpg)

How do i get rid of the newline "\n"?

Pure code:

```
TextIDNumber = Text(App, height = "1", width = "25", bd = "4")
TextIDNumber.place(x = 550, y = 250)
TextIDNumber.config(font =("bold", 20))
TextSurname = Text(App, height = "1", width = "25", bd = "4")
TextSurname.place(x = 550, y = 350)
TextSurname.config(font =("bold", 20))



def CheckInputUI():
    IDNumber = TextIDNumber.get("1.0", END)
    Surname = TextSurname.get("1.0", END)
    print (Surname, IDNumber)
    print ("")
    print (Surname + IDNumber)
```

The shortest possible code that reproduces your problem, that we can run on our own machines:

```
from tkinter import *


App = Tk()

#This maximises the window
w = App.winfo_screenwidth()
h = App.winfo_screenheight()

App.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % ((w-10), (h-30)))

TextIDNumber = Text(App, height = "1", width = "25", bd = "4")
TextIDNumber.place(x = 550, y = 250)
TextIDNumber.config(font =("bold", 20))
TextSurname = Text(App, height = "1", width = "25", bd = "4")
TextSurname.place(x = 550, y = 350)
TextSurname.config(font =("bold", 20))

def PrintInfo():
    IDNumber = TextIDNumber.get("1.0", END)
    Surname = TextSurname.get("1.0", END)
    print (Surname, IDNumber)
    print ("")
    print (Surname + IDNumber)

DoneButton = Button(App, text = " Done ", font = ("bold", 18), command = PrintInfo).place(x = 400,y = 800)
```

I use the prints to display my work to the shell only (so i could find the root of the problem, in other words where the newlines where being added), they server no other purpose.

Comment: Please post pure code instead of pictures in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: All of the code? or just what the picture contains in "pure code"?

Comment: Do you perhaps have `CheckInputUI` bound to the Enter key?

Comment: My python days are behind me this was just an interesting waste of time rly,

Comment: A new line is represented by `"\n"` not `"/n"`.

Comment: i can post a full version of "CheckInputUI if necessary"

Comment: What's necessary is the shortest possible code that reproduces your problem, that we can run on our own machines.

Comment: Have you tried using `.strip("\n")` ? with the correct notation for newlines?

Comment: I have just tried that, it doesn't work...

Comment: You've changed the `get` lines to `..."1.0", END).strip()` and it didn't work?

Comment: OMG you guys are geniuses this question has been up like 30 minutes, and its already solved.

Comment: thankyou tigerhawk... I hope you all have a good day,

Comment: You can also omit the very last unwanted additional character by changing the index: `..."1.0", 'end-1 chars)'`.

Comment: I will accept the thanks as well...

Answer (score 0):

The text widget guarantees that there is always a newline at the end, even if there isn't one in the actual data. To get the all of the data from the widget *except* this special newline, use `"end-1c"` (end minus one character) when getting the data:

```
IDNumber = TextIDNumber.get("1.0", "end-1c")
Surname = TextSurname.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

If there's a chance that blank lines will get added to the data, you can strip off all trailing whitespace with `strip`:

```
IDNumber = TextIDNumber.get("1.0", END).rstrip()
Surname = TextSurname.get("1.0", END).rstrip()
```